# FireBase Authencation : "INVALID_TOKEN: Could not parse auth token."

Tags: firebase

```
dataservice.getToken().success(function (token) {
        console.log(token);
        rootRef.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Login Failed!', error);
            } else {
                console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
            }
        });
    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log("Not able to get token data");
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I always get "INVALID_TOKEN: Could not parse auth token." However If I copy the paste token from the console log and run it , then it works fine. The dataType of token is string and expected is also String.

Code Used to create Auth token :

```
public class FirebaseHelper {

public static final String SECRET = "<secret key>";

public static final String APP_URL = "<firebase url>";

public String getToken(final String Id) {

    Map<String, Object> authPayload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    authPayload.put("uid", Id);

    TokenGenerator tokenGenerator = new TokenGenerator(SECRET);
    String token = tokenGenerator.createToken(authPayload);

    return token;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code the creates the token? Or even a token itself?

Comment: I have added the code to generate tokens. Thanks